# При запуске локального приложения в Битрикс24 нет результата, только код

Tags: php, битрикс24

создаю тестовый пустой Битрикс24. также создаю локальное приложение и устанавливаю в него следующий файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $queryUrl = 'https://'.$_REQUEST['DOMAIN'].'/rest/user.current.json';

    $queryData = http_build_query(array(
        "auth" => $_REQUEST['AUTH_ID']
    ));

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
    ));

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $result['result']['NAME'].' '.$result['result']['LAST_NAME'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так? пример взят из документации.

Comment: Видимо у вас локально в сервере отключена поддержка `PHP` и по этой причине браузер выдаёт `PHP` код как строку )) Если конечно вы вставили пхп код в ․php файл  а не ․html

Comment: @Arsen да, дело оказывается в сервере) спасибо за наводку)